# Convert hhmmss to time in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a column of times in `hhmmss` format.  What is a formula to convert them to an Excel Time value?

Note that they will not necessarily be zero-padded.  E.g., `09:21:34` might appear as `92134` instead of `092134`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If cell A1 contains a time like "112345" then the most elegant conversion formula is:

```
=--TEXT(A1,"00\:00\:00")
```

A perhaps more understandable formula is

```
=TIME(A1/10000,MOD(A1/100,100),MOD(A1,100))
```

Note that both of these work regardless of whether the time is zero-padded.